# how to plot a bar chart using plotly using python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

i have the below dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dept':['dept1','dept2','dept3','dept4','dept5'],
                 'subd':['hndf','nbf','asx','qwe','def'],
                 'jju':['0','1','1','NA','1'],
                 'rob':['1','0','NA','1','1'],
                 'ans':['0','0','1','NA','1'],
                 'zsd':['1','NA','1','1','1'],
                 'count':['4','3','3','2','4']}


        dept    subd      jju     rob  ans  zsd count
0      dept1    hndf       0      1     0      1    4
1      dept2     nbf       1      0     0      NA   3
2      dept3     asx       1      NA    1      1    3
3      dept4     qwe       NA     1    NA      1    2
4      dept5     def       1      1    1       1    4
```

I need to plot a bar plot using **plotly.graph_objs** package

Where the

- X axis is the `df.loc[:, 'jju':'zsd']`
- Y axis is the count of **'0'** and **'1'**

**expected result each item on the X axis will have 2 bars**

for now i tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

res = []
for col in df.loc[:, 'jju':'zsd'].columns:
    res.append(
       go.Bar(
       x= df.index.values.tolist(),
       y = df[col].values.tolist(),
       name = col
       )
    )
layout = go.Layout(barmode = 'group')
fig = go.Figure(data = res,layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

But it doesn't return what i want so where i did it wrong ??

Comment: What will be the response to 'NA'?

Comment: @r-beginners can't i ignore it ?

Comment: You want to draw a bar chart with a sum of 1 and 0s.

Comment: correct for each column  i want to draw a chart that show for example :
 `jju 1 =>3 0=>1
ans 1=>2 0=>2
zsd 1=>4 0 =>0` 

if you understand what i mean.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Is there an expected output?

Comment: Yes the expected output is a bar chart that includes columns [:,jju: zsd] on the X axis 
And each colum will have 2 grouped bars 0 & 1 
The Y axis will display the count of each 0 & 1 for each column.

Comment: Try this: `res = []
i = 0
for col in df.columns:
    print(df.iloc[i])
    res.append(
       go.Bar(
       x= df.columns,
       y = df.iloc[i].values.tolist(),
       name = col
       )
    )
    i += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
import plotly.express as px
fig=px.histogram(df,x=['jju','rob','ans','zsd'],barmode="group")
fig.show()
```

If you need to neglect the "NA" you should replace them by `np.nan` values :

```
df=df.replace('NA',np.nan)
fig=px.histogram(df,x=['jju','rob','ans','zsd'],barmode="group")
fig.show()
```